# Selecting a node that provides a service

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to understand how a particular node (service-proxy) is selected when there are more than one node that provides the same service.
I understand, in this case every service-proxy on each participating node listens on the well-known IP:port (portal) of the particular service (well, it configures iptables rule to catch the packets coming to the portal), and when a request arrives to the node with the portal, iptables rules forward the request to the service-proxy. That is all right.
Though, my problem is, if more than a single node uses the same IP address (a.k.a. virtual IP address), how the request is routed to a particular node, and how that node is selected from the available set?

Thank you!
Best regards,
Laszlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the proxy will do a simple round-robin load balancing across the set of pods that are backing a service.  Over time, we want to have more/smarter options here, but we find that this simple policy can work in a lot of situations.

Comment: I understand, that once the request is routed to a specific service-proxy on a specific node, then the service-proxy can use round-robin to select a pod on that node. But if the same service is provided by 3 nodes(and consequently 3 service-proxies, assuming 1 proxy per node), how a specific node is selected by the client, and how the request is routed to the selected node, if all the nodes can be reached with the same IP address (the virtual IP).

Comment: It works like this -- traffic from a pod goes to the service IP.  That then (via iptables right now) gets directed to the proxy server that sits on the local node.  It then forwards that connection to any one of the backends that are identified by the service label query.


If you want to target a single instance of the backend you won't want to use the proxy but instead look up the IP of the pod you are interested in and contact that pod directly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it is clear now. So service proxies on all nodes in the cluster create the iptables rule, not only on the nodes where service related pods are deployed. And consequently , packets targeted to the virtual IP never leave a node. Thanks!